# liboctinterp.so.3 - cannot open shared object file

Tags: shared-libraries, octave

I am working on an old shell script that calls Octave at some point, with a `file.m` as argument.
The part of the code that causes the error just runs: `octave -q my_file.m` (and other arguments)

The error is:

> select.oct: failed to load: liboctinterp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The code uses to work with Octave 4.4.1 on a server, but I can’t make it run on my PC, in local.

Do you think that if I install octave-4.4.1 it could fix the problem? Or do you think Octaves’ version is unlinked to the issue? (As for the moment I have also tried compiling octave-4.4.1 from source but I am encountering a problem during compilation too, so I just want to be sure it could work.)

Or maybe this shared library has nothing to do with octave and I can get it elsewhere?
When I run:

```
ldconfig -p | grep liboctinterp.so.
```

it returns:

```
liboctinterp.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liboctinterp.so.7
```

I think it means I need an older version of that shared library, but can’t find it… I think it uses to comes with octave-4.4.1?

I don’t really know what to do here. Any help is welcomed!

**System information**

- OS: Linux Mint 20
- Octave version: GNU Octave, version 5.2.0
- Installation method: sudo apt-get install octave

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32829531/7328782) where you originally posted your question as an answer. The answer there clearly says that Oct files are not compatible across versions of Octave. You need to recompile your `select.oct` file. If you can't do that, you need to downgrade Octave to 4.4.x.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think OP wants an answer to simply explain what should they do. Could you make your comment as an answer?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I apologise for asking a question that has already been asked! I just wanted to be sure downgrading to Octave 4.4.x would get me liboctinterp.so.3. I've accepted the proposition to mark this question as a duplicate. Best, Lloyd